# Cancel AsyncTask in Fragment in onPause

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to stop or cancel the AsyncTask if onPause is called.
in onPause:

```
 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e("ONPAUSE", "CALLED");
        async.cancel(true);
    }
```

and in doBackground:

```
if (!isCancelled()) {
                Log.e("RUNNING","TAB3");
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(StaticVariables.url_customer_details + CustomerID);
                    Log.e("URL", "is " + url.toString());
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    con.setUseCaches(true);
                    String readStream = readStream(con.getInputStream());

                    System.out.println(readStream);

                    arr = new JSONArray(readStream);
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        object = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    }
                    return readStream;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("CANCELLED","TAB3");
                return null;
            }
```

But the Log will never say "CANCELLED"..

Comment: an example for cancelling an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override **onCancelled** method in **async task** to check it is cancelled or not.

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
  Log.e("CANCELLED","TAB3");      
  super.onCancelled();
}
```

**If you're doing computations:**

You have to check **isCancelled()** periodically. But i think, your are not doing computations.

> Cancelling a task
>
> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean).
>   Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to
>   return true.
>
> After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of
>   onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[])
>   returns.
>
> To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should
>   always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from
>   doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)